# Troubleshooting steps for module not appearing in System->configuration->advanced

Tags: module, troubleshooting

I have installed a module in a Magento site which does not appear when I check `System->configuration->advanced` in the back end.

So far I have tried following things

- turned off compilation,
- logged in and out numerous times,
- reindexed and
- deleted the cache.

I'm very confused about this because whenever I've made a module (whether it worked or not) the name + enabled or disable option always appears in this section.

This is the `app/etc/modules/Customweb_BarclaycardCw.xml` file

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <config>
             <modules>
                    <Customweb_BarclaycardCw>
                         <active>true</active>
                         <codePool>local</codePool>
                         <depends>
                            <Mage_Payment/>
                            <Mage_Api/>
                         </depends>
                         <version>1.3.0</version>
                    </Customweb_BarclaycardCw>
            </modules>
        </config>
```

I can't think of anything else to do to try to fix this so all suggestions are welcome

`config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <config>
    <modules>
        <Customweb_BarclaycardCw>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </Customweb_BarclaycardCw>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <barclaycardcw>
                <class>Customweb_BarclaycardCw_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>barclaycardcw_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </barclaycardcw>
            <barclaycardcw_mysql4>
                <class>Customweb_BarclaycardCw_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <aliasdata>
                        <table>barclaycardcw_alias_data</table>
                    </aliasdata>
                    <customercontext>
                        <table>barclaycardcw_customer_context</table>
                    </customercontext>
                    <transaction>
                        <table>barclaycardcw_transaction</table>
                    </transaction>
                    <storage>
                        <table>barclaycardcw_storage</table>
                    </storage>
                </entities>
            </barclaycardcw_mysql4>

            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <cart>Customweb_BarclaycardCw_Model_Checkout_Cart</cart>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <barclaycardcw><class>Customweb_BarclaycardCw_Block</class></barclaycardcw>

            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_invoice_view>Customweb_BarclaycardCw_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Invoice_View</sales_order_invoice_view>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <BarclaycardCw>
                <class>Customweb_BarclaycardCw_Helper</class>
            </BarclaycardCw>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <barclaycardcw_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </barclaycardcw_write>
            <barclaycardcw_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </barclaycardcw_read>
            <barclaycardcw_setup>
                 <setup>
                    <module>Customweb_BarclaycardCw</module>
                    <class>Customweb_BarclaycardCw_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                 </setup>
            </barclaycardcw_setup>
        </resources>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_view_construct>
                <observers>
                    <barclaycardcw_invoice_view>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Customweb_BarclaycardCw_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>invoiceView</method>
                    </barclaycardcw_invoice_view>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_view_construct>
            <checkout_cart_init>
                <observers>
                    <barclaycardcw_init_cart>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Customweb_BarclaycardCw_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>initCart</method>
                    </barclaycardcw_init_cart>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_init>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <barclaycardcw_save_order>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Customweb_BarclaycardCw_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>saveOrder</method>
                    </barclaycardcw_save_order>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
            <sales_order_payment_capture>
                <observers>
                    <barclaycardcw_capture_payment>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Customweb_BarclaycardCw_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>capturePayment</method>
                    </barclaycardcw_capture_payment>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_payment_capture>
            <order_cancel_after>
                <observers>
                    <barclaycardcw_cancel_order>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Customweb_BarclaycardCw_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>cancelOrder</method>
                    </barclaycardcw_cancel_order>
                </observers>
            </order_cancel_after>
            <controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_create_save>
                <observers>
                    <barclaycardcw_moto_after_save>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Customweb_BarclaycardCw_Model_MotoObserver</class>
                        <method>postOrderSave</method>
                    </barclaycardcw_moto_after_save>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_create_save>
            <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_create_save>
                <observers>
                    <barclaycardcw_moto_before_save>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Customweb_BarclaycardCw_Model_MotoObserver</class>
                        <method>beforeOrderSave</method>
                    </barclaycardcw_moto_before_save>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_create_save>
        </events>
        <sales>
            <order>
                <statuses>
                    <canceled_barclaycardcw translate="label">
                        <label>Canceled BarclaycardCw</label>
                    </canceled_barclaycardcw>
                    <pending_barclaycardcw translate="label">
                        <label>Pending BarclaycardCw</label>
                    </pending_barclaycardcw>
                </statuses>
                <states>
                    <canceled>
                        <statuses>
                            <canceled_barclaycardcw />
                        </statuses>
                    </canceled>
                    <pending_payment>
                        <statuses>
                            <pending_barclaycardcw />
                        </statuses>
                    </pending_payment>
                </states>
            </order>
        </sales>
    </global>

    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <barclaycardcw>
                    <file>barclaycardcw.xml</file>
                </barclaycardcw>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Customweb_BarclaycardCw>
                    <files>
                        <default>Customweb_BarclaycardCw.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Customweb_BarclaycardCw>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>

    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <barclaycardcw_cron>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>barclaycardcw/CronObserver::executeCron</model>
                </run>
            </barclaycardcw_cron>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Customweb_BarclaycardCw after="Mage_Adminhtml">Customweb_BarclaycardCw</Customweb_BarclaycardCw>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <frontend>
        <secure_url>
            <barclaycardcw>/BarclaycardCw/</barclaycardcw>
        </secure_url>
        <blocks>
            <BarclaycardCw>
                <class>Customweb_BarclaycardCw_Block</class>
            </BarclaycardCw>
        </blocks>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <barclaycardcw>
                    <file>barclaycardcw.xml</file>
                </barclaycardcw>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <routers>
            <BarclaycardCw>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Customweb_BarclaycardCw</module>
                    <frontName>BarclaycardCw</frontName>
                </args>
            </BarclaycardCw>
        </routers>

        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Customweb_BarclaycardCw>
                    <files>
                        <default>Customweb_BarclaycardCw.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Customweb_BarclaycardCw>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
    <default>
        <barclaycardcw>
            <general>
                <version>1.2.148</version>
                <operation_mode>test</operation_mode>
                <pspid></pspid>
                <test_pspid></test_pspid>
                <live_sha_passphrase_in></live_sha_passphrase_in>
                <live_sha_passphrase_out></live_sha_passphrase_out>
                <test_sha_passphrase_in></test_sha_passphrase_in>
                <test_sha_passphrase_out></test_sha_passphrase_out>
                <hash_method>sha512</hash_method>
                <order_id_schema>order_{id}</order_id_schema>
                <order_description_schema>Order {id}</order_description_schema>
                <template>default</template>
                <template_url></template_url>
                <shop_id></shop_id>
                <api_user_id></api_user_id>
                <api_password></api_password>
                <alias_usage_message></alias_usage_message>
                <transaction_updates>inactive</transaction_updates>
                <cancel_existing_orders>0</cancel_existing_orders>
                <wait_for_success>0</wait_for_success>
            </general>
        </barclaycardcw>
        <payment>
            <barclaycardcw_mastercard>
                <model>barclaycardcw/Method_MasterCard</model>
                <active>0</active>
                <title>MasterCard</title>
                <description>Pay with MasterCard</description>
                <show_image>1</show_image>
                <show_payment_id>1</show_payment_id>
                <Currency>1</Currency>
                <use_base_currency>0</use_base_currency>
                <allowspecific></allowspecific>
                <specificcountry></specificcountry>
                <sort_order></sort_order>
                <min_order_total></min_order_total>
                <max_order_total></max_order_total>
                <settlement>settlement_direct</settlement>
                <capturing>direct</capturing>
                <status_authorized>pending</status_authorized>
                <status_uncertain>holded</status_uncertain>
                <status_captured>no_status_change</status_captured>
                <status_success_after_uncertain>no_status_change</status_success_after_uncertain>
                <status_refused_after_uncertain>no_status_change</status_refused_after_uncertain>
                <refusing_threshold>3</refusing_threshold>
                <three_d_secure_behavior>never</three_d_secure_behavior>
                <three_d_secure_country_list></three_d_secure_country_list>
                <country_check>inactive</country_check>
                <authorizationMethod>PaymentPage</authorizationMethod>
                <alias_manager>inactive</alias_manager>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            </barclaycardcw_mastercard>
            <barclaycardcw_creditcard>
                <model>barclaycardcw/Method_CreditCard</model>
                <active>0</active>
                <title>Credit Card</title>
                <description>Pay with Credit Card</description>
                <show_image>1</show_image>
                <show_payment_id>1</show_payment_id>
                <Currency>1</Currency>
                <use_base_currency>0</use_base_currency>
                <allowspecific></allowspecific>
                <specificcountry></specificcountry>
                <sort_order></sort_order>
                <min_order_total></min_order_total>
                <max_order_total></max_order_total>
                <settlement>settlement_direct</settlement>
                <capturing>direct</capturing>
                <payment_method_listing>2</payment_method_listing>
                <credit_card_brands>visa,mastercard,americanexpress,jcb,maestro,cartebleu,solo</credit_card_brands>
                <status_authorized>pending</status_authorized>
                <status_uncertain>holded</status_uncertain>
                <status_captured>no_status_change</status_captured>
                <status_success_after_uncertain>no_status_change</status_success_after_uncertain>
                <status_refused_after_uncertain>no_status_change</status_refused_after_uncertain>
                <refusing_threshold>3</refusing_threshold>
                <three_d_secure_behavior>never</three_d_secure_behavior>
                <three_d_secure_country_list></three_d_secure_country_list>
                <country_check>inactive</country_check>
                <authorizationMethod>PaymentPage</authorizationMethod>
                <alias_manager>inactive</alias_manager>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            </barclaycardcw_creditcard>
            <barclaycardcw_americanexpress>
                <model>barclaycardcw/Method_AmericanExpress</model>
                <active>0</active>
                <title>American Express</title>
                <description>Pay with American Express</description>
                <show_image>1</show_image>
                <show_payment_id>1</show_payment_id>
                <Currency>1</Currency>
                <use_base_currency>0</use_base_currency>
                <allowspecific></allowspecific>
                <specificcountry></specificcountry>
                <sort_order></sort_order>
                <min_order_total></min_order_total>
                <max_order_total></max_order_total>
                <settlement>settlement_direct</settlement>
                <capturing>direct</capturing>
                <status_authorized>pending</status_authorized>
                <status_uncertain>holded</status_uncertain>
                <status_captured>no_status_change</status_captured>
                <status_success_after_uncertain>no_status_change</status_success_after_uncertain>
                <status_refused_after_uncertain>no_status_change</status_refused_after_uncertain>
                <refusing_threshold>3</refusing_threshold>
                <country_check>inactive</country_check>
                <authorizationMethod>PaymentPage</authorizationMethod>
                <alias_manager>inactive</alias_manager>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            </barclaycardcw_americanexpress>
            <barclaycardcw_jcb>
                <model>barclaycardcw/Method_Jcb</model>
                <active>0</active>
                <title>JCB</title>
                <description>Pay with JCB</description>
                <show_image>1</show_image>
                <show_payment_id>1</show_payment_id>
                <Currency>1</Currency>
                <use_base_currency>0</use_base_currency>
                <allowspecific></allowspecific>
                <specificcountry></specificcountry>
                <sort_order></sort_order>
                <min_order_total></min_order_total>
                <max_order_total></max_order_total>
                <settlement>settlement_direct</settlement>
                <capturing>direct</capturing>
                <status_authorized>pending</status_authorized>
                <status_uncertain>holded</status_uncertain>
                <status_captured>no_status_change</status_captured>
                <status_success_after_uncertain>no_status_change</status_success_after_uncertain>
                <status_refused_after_uncertain>no_status_change</status_refused_after_uncertain>
                <refusing_threshold>3</refusing_threshold>
                <country_check>inactive</country_check>
                <authorizationMethod>PaymentPage</authorizationMethod>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            </barclaycardcw_jcb>
            <barclaycardcw_visa>
                <model>barclaycardcw/Method_Visa</model>
                <active>0</active>
                <title>Visa</title>
                <description>Pay with Visa</description>
                <show_image>1</show_image>
                <show_payment_id>1</show_payment_id>
                <Currency>1</Currency>
                <use_base_currency>0</use_base_currency>
                <allowspecific></allowspecific>
                <specificcountry></specificcountry>
                <sort_order></sort_order>
                <min_order_total></min_order_total>
                <max_order_total></max_order_total>
                <settlement>settlement_direct</settlement>
                <capturing>direct</capturing>
                <status_authorized>pending</status_authorized>
                <status_uncertain>holded</status_uncertain>
                <status_captured>no_status_change</status_captured>
                <status_success_after_uncertain>no_status_change</status_success_after_uncertain>
                <status_refused_after_uncertain>no_status_change</status_refused_after_uncertain>
                <refusing_threshold>3</refusing_threshold>
                <three_d_secure_behavior>never</three_d_secure_behavior>
                <three_d_secure_country_list></three_d_secure_country_list>
                <country_check>inactive</country_check>
                <authorizationMethod>PaymentPage</authorizationMethod>
                <alias_manager>inactive</alias_manager>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            </barclaycardcw_visa>
            <barclaycardcw_maestro>
                <model>barclaycardcw/Method_Maestro</model>
                <active>0</active>
                <title>Maestro</title>
                <description>Pay with Maestro</description>
                <show_image>1</show_image>
                <show_payment_id>1</show_payment_id>
                <Currency>1</Currency>
                <use_base_currency>0</use_base_currency>
                <allowspecific></allowspecific>
                <specificcountry></specificcountry>
                <sort_order></sort_order>
                <min_order_total></min_order_total>
                <max_order_total></max_order_total>
                <settlement>settlement_direct</settlement>
                <capturing>direct</capturing>
                <status_authorized>pending</status_authorized>
                <status_uncertain>holded</status_uncertain>
                <status_captured>no_status_change</status_captured>
                <status_success_after_uncertain>no_status_change</status_success_after_uncertain>
                <status_refused_after_uncertain>no_status_change</status_refused_after_uncertain>
                <refusing_threshold>3</refusing_threshold>
                <country_check>inactive</country_check>
                <authorizationMethod>PaymentPage</authorizationMethod>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            </barclaycardcw_maestro>
        </payment>
    </default>
    </config>
```

Adminhtml.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
<menu>
     <system>
        <children>
            <barclaycardcw translate="title" module="BarclaycardCw">
                <title>Barclaycard</title>
                <action>adminhtml/configbarclaycardcw</action>
                <sort_order>109</sort_order>
            </barclaycardcw>
        </children>
     </system>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <barclaycardcw>
                            <title>Barclaycard</title>
                            <sort_order>16</sort_order>
                        </barclaycardcw>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <barclaycardcw translate="title" module="BarclaycardCw">
                                    <title>Barclaycard</title>
                                </barclaycardcw>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
</config>
```

Comment: please post the config.xml

Comment: In order to see your module in backend, you need to create module directories at least in backend. ie create the directory `app\code\local\Customweb\BarclaycardCw`

Comment: @programmer_rkt This exists already

Comment: @MTM added it now

Comment: post  adminhtml.xml if you are using

Comment: @MTM it's there now

Comment: user module="barclaycardcw" instead of capitals

Comment: @MTM what file are you talking about for that change?

Comment: I can see `module="BarclaycardCw"` in adminhtml.xml so replace it with `module="barclaycardcw"`  but if u are using in config.xml too you have to do it same way there as well

Comment: this didn't work unfortunately, i also logged out and reindexed and flushed cache to make sure

Comment: and i hope the file name `adminhtml.xml` is itself in small caps.

Comment: Thomas Ryan,please check <?xml verion tag is  in start first line of   Customweb_BarclaycardCw.xml or not

Comment: @AmitBera it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the module to a staging server we use prior to live deploys. This domain and the live domain are registered with the Module provider. Once on the staging site it turned up in the module listing page.

This still seems like strange behaviour to me because I thought even if it doesn't work it should show up under System->Configuration->advanced. Anyway this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding in Magento, in order to see your module status in backend via `System  >  Configuration  >  Advanced`, you need to activation file of your module inside `app\etc\modules` directory and then folder structure is defined well in the appropriate code pool directory.

So my strong believe is, you have some problem that exist in the activation file of the module itself. So try this code directly copying it to your activation file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
          <Customweb_BarclaycardCw>
                 <active>true</active>
                 <codePool>local</codePool>
                 <depends>
                      <Mage_Payment />
                      <Mage_Api />
                  </depends>
           </Customweb_BarclaycardCw>
     </modules>
</config>
```

I have removed `version` node that was present in your activation file and removed unwanted spaces.

Make sure the directory structure `app\code\local\Customweb\BarclaycardCw\` is present in your application.

Now try again.

Comment: I tried this along with reindex, cache flush and logging out but it didn't work

Comment: try @MTM solution first. If didn't work. Make a backup of your module and then leave the directory structure and activation file in the application. Check whether module appeared in admin. If yes, then put files i. `local` folder one by one and thus find which file makes problem

Comment: most importantly check log files and see it gives any hint